# Is there some general rules to remember shortcut?

Tags: workflow, shortcut

I am using blender for a week and Im really struggled on understanding why any function have specifically that hotkeys that it have. For example: its clear that "a" key may stand for "add" and "apply" but is there some explanation of why specifically "**shift**+a" is add and "**ctrl**+a" is apply?
Some at least mnemonic rules can ease a workflow dramatically.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no "rules" in terms of shortcuts.

Comment: The only 'rule' is that 'alt' generally clears something. E.g. 'A' selects all and Alt+A clears. Ctrl+P parents, Alt+P clears. 'G' moves, Alt+G clears location.